# Trying to edit Google Sheets alphabetize sheets script to place specific named sheets in front of rest

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

OK, so I have a working script that moves sheets within a spreadsheet into alphabetical order. However, I have a couple of sheets that I do not want to move from being the first two sheets in the spreadsheet, named "Index" and "Template". Right now as long as I leave them in the first two spots, the script will ignore them and alphabetize after that, but if they are not in the two first spots they end up at the end as the other sheets are alphabetized in front of them. To protect against someone adding a sheet in the first spot or otherwise moving the Index or Template sheets, I want them to auto move back to the first two places with all other sheets alphabetical afterwards.

I can't figure out where in the code I need to have the Index and Template move to the first two positions.

Current code, with link that I based most of it from.

```
//https://support.google.com/docs/thread/2806598/any-way-to-sort-sheets-in-alphabetical-order-in-my-workbook?hl=en

function sortSheetsByName() {
  var aSheets = new Array();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets)
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    if(
       (sheet.getName() == "Index") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "Template") 
      ) continue;
    aSheets.push(ss.getSheets()[s].getName());
  }
  if(aSheets.length)
  {
    aSheets.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < aSheets.length; i++)
    {
      var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName(aSheets[i]);
      if(theSheet.getIndex() != i + 3) //This was i + 1, changing it to 3 starts from third sheet
      {
        ss.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
        ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 3);  //This was i + 1, changing it to 3 starts from third sheet
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some code snippets I was trying:

```
var indexSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Index")
ss.moveActiveSheet(1);
var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Template")
ss.moveActiveSheet(2);
```

```
// Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
    if(
       (sheet.getName() == "Index") || 
       (sheet.getName() == "Template")
      ) continue;
```

EDIT: With answer, and making variables to more easily be able to change the names of which sheets should not be included in the alphabetization, we have:

```
var firstSheet = "Index";
var secondSheet = "Template";

function sortSheetsByName() {
  var aSheets = new Array();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s in allsheets)
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    if(
       (sheet.getName() == firstSheet) || 
       (sheet.getName() == secondSheet) 
      ) continue;
    aSheets.push(ss.getSheets()[s].getName());
  }
  if(aSheets.length)
  {
    ss.getSheetByName(firstSheet).activate()
    ss.moveActiveSheet(1)
    ss.getSheetByName(secondSheet).activate()
    ss.moveActiveSheet(2)
    aSheets.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < aSheets.length; i++)
    {
      var theSheet = ss.getSheetByName(aSheets[i]);
      if(theSheet.getIndex() != i + 3)
      {
        ss.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
        ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 3);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to activate the sheets before moving them rather than just obtaining the Sheet objects.*

#### Code Change:

After your final `if (aSheets.length)` conditional, you need to add the following lines:

```js
ss.getSheetByName("Index").activate()
ss.moveActiveSheet(1)
ss.getSheetByName("Template").activate()
ss.moveActiveSheet(2)
```

#### References:

- [Class Sheet - activate() | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate())
- [Class Spreadsheet - moveActiveSheet(pos) | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveactivesheetpos)

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! I can't remember if I tried using activate properly before, but  putting it after that if (aSheets.length) line inside the conditional makes it work correctly each time.

Comment: Note: Not suitable for an onEdit script, as every time to you try to type something it runs and you are put on whatever the last activated sheet of the script is.

Comment: Don't re-add fluff: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/6296561 - "hope this helps" are among the things classified as fluff on Stack Overflow, and removing them is actually _encouraged_.

Comment: You already told me this and I've stopped, you're not achieving anything new by keep commenting this. @Zoe